# How to generate a (html) file from a view in Django

Tags: django, file, templates, view

I have a Django-driven website with several applications which are dynamically updated, but not too often, like "About", "Our services", etc. They have a two-level structure of pages, which I want to reflect in the top pop-up menu (see the picture).

I could make it as a custom simple_tag called each time from the base.html template. It would generate a menu each time a user opens or reloads a page, but think it is very costly since the app structure is changed seldom (say, once a year).

[image: piece of the popup menu]

Instead, I want to like to generate an HTML code of the menu each time the app structure is updated. It will be stored as a statical HTML file, so my base.html will include the menu as a ready piece of code.

Are there recipes on how to generate an HTML file from the views (CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `render_to_string` function from django that generated the html result from a template:

```
from django.template import loader

content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context)
```

content contains the html result of rendering. You can add request object in the `render_to_string` function if needed.

you can find documentation about function here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looks promising. I'll try and write here.

Comment: @MichaelRomanov ok, you can mark as resolved for closing questions ;)

Comment: Yes, I will, just need some more help. Thanks to Lucas Grugru, I <mostly> solved the problem with the `render_to_string` function. It perfectly works with my PageUpdateView. Specifically, I rewrote get_success_url method (I choose this one because it seems to be the last one which works in terms of time). In this method, I select my objects (pages and subpages), pass them as a context to the function 'render_to_string' together with a template, and write the generated string to HTML file. Everything works great with UpdateView, but I have an issue with DeleteView.

Comment: Specifically, when I select my objects with a queryset, they are selected together with the deleted object, so the generated menu is out-of-date. Please help me, how to exclude the deleted object from my queryset.

Comment: @MichaelRomanov probably better if you create new post with detail and code please :)

Comment: I've checked your answer as accepted. Does it mean that the question is solved?

Comment: @MichaelRomanov Yes